# Sorting strings alphabetically in an array. Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have to sort strings in an array for a school project. Our teacher won't allow us to use array,sort().
i have to use 2 sort methods but they aren't working too well.

The first one returns double of each value. ie John, jack, adam, tom will return adam,adam,jack,jack,john,john,tom,tom.

```
public static void sort() {
        inputFileNames();//inputs list of names from a file.
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                if (stArr[i].compareTo(stArr[j])>0) {
                    temp = stArr[i];
                    stArr[i] = stArr[j];
                    stArr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        display("The names are: ");// method to display array 
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

the second sort doesn' run:

```
public static void bubbleSort() {
        inputFileNames();
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (stArr[j].compareTo(stArr[j+1])>0) {
                    temp = stArr[j];
                    stArr[j] = stArr[j + 1];
                    stArr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        display("The names are: ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

input and display:

```
static void display(String heading) {
    System.out.println(heading + "\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println(stArr[i]);
    }
}

static void inputFileNames() {
    try {
        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));
        while (scFile.hasNext()) {
            stArr[size] = scFile.nextLine();
            size++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `display()`? The duplication error is most likely there. Array in Java are fixed-length, therefore even if your algorithm was buggy, it's impossbile there are twice as many entries in the array then before.

Comment: `inputFileNames()` could also be reading the names twice so they are sorted together.

Comment: Or that, yes. So please post that as well, or output the contents of the array before sorting / view them in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

```
 /* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int i,j;
    String[] stArr = new String[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        stArr[i]=sc.next();
       // System.out.println(stArr[i]);
    }
    //inputs list of names from a file.
    for (i = 0; i < n  ; i++) {
        for (j = i+1 ; j < n; j++) {
            if (stArr[i].compareTo(stArr[j])>0)
            {
               String temp = stArr[i];
                stArr[i] = stArr[j];
                stArr[j] = temp;
               // System.out.println(stArr[i]);
            //    System.out.println(stArr[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(stArr[i]);
    }


    // your code goes here
}
}
```

This Is the answer for first code. I am not good in file handling so you have to use your input method. I know Scanner thats why i have used here.

In Your Second Example Your j loop is wrong it should be for ( j = 0; j <= i-1; j++). And Please Mark It as answer if your problem is solved

Comment: Thanks for the answer but our teacher wont allow us to use array.sort()